# Java Calendar Not working

Tags: java

So, by using

```
Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR
```

I keep getting six (even though its 7/12/13). I'll change my date, try again, still won't work. I'll change the date **and** restart, it just returns 6. Is Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR not supposed to return the day of the year anymore?

Comment: it never returned current day, its a Constant...

Comment: Are you from the future? 7/12/13?

Comment: you should read javadoc at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: @woz Heh, I just looked at my clock before I forgot to turn it back.
Sorry about it "not being a real question". Its 1 in the morning, so I am quite tired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR` is a constant representing the field that contains the day-of-year.  It's numeric value (6, apparently) has no meaning beyond being not equal to any of the other field constants.

You want

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```